# Simulation time change multisim

Tags: time, simulation

Is it possible to change the simulation steps in multisim? (more exact and more detailed simulation results). I have an output that changes quite fast in time, so at the moment the measurements are very rough and unrefined

Comment: What are you refering to, when you mention "multisim"? Is it something like [Multipass](http://i.imgur.com/nRSwTRs.gif)?

Comment: Since Multisim is Circuit Design software, this question might fit better at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I believe so.  It took me a minute to find this myself.  Go to the area where you hit the "Play" icon to start the simulation.  It will say "Interactive" to the right.  Click on that.  Under the "Interactive Simulation" option, Analysis Parameters tab, (you will already be at that tab by default), check the box for "Maximum time step (TMAX)".

Change this number to change how fast the simulation runs.  This will set how many seconds each time step represents. This means that TMAX of 1 second will be very fast (each step moves through one second of simulated time). If you set it to something slower like .00001, that might work.  I found 1e-006 to be a good setting.